# Style to ng5-slider in angular is not applied

Tags: html, angular, css, sass

I have an Angular project with ng5-slider. I am following following article:

https://github.com/angular-slider/ng5-slider/blob/master/STYLING.md

I am trying to change the font size:
[image]

scss:

```
.custom-slider {
    .ng5-slider {
      .ng5-slider-selection {
        background: rgb(255, 255, 0) !important;
      }

      .ng5-slider-span {
        background-color: red !important;
        font-size: 6px;
      }

      .ng5-slider-pointer{
        background-color: red !important;
        font-size: 6px;
      }
    }
  }

  .ng5-slider .ng5-slider-pointer{
    height: 16px !important;
    background-color: red !important;
  }

  .ng5-slider-span{
    background-color: red !important;
  }
```

html:

```
 <div class="custom-slider">
     <ng5-slider [(value)]="value" [options]="options"></ng5-slider>
 </div>
```

No matter what I add of styles it is not applied. I can see in Chrome following is generated:

```
<ng5-slider _ngcontent-c0="" class="ng5-slider" _nghost-c1="" ng-reflect-value="50"
    ng-reflect-options="[object Object]"><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar-wrapper ng5-slider-left-out-selection" ng5sliderleftoutselelem=""
        style="visibility: hidden;"><span _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar"></span></span><span
        _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar-wrapper ng5-slider-right-out-selection"
        ng5sliderrightoutselelem="" style="visibility: hidden;"><span _ngcontent-c1=""
            class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar"></span></span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar-wrapper" ng5sliderfullbarelem=""><span _ngcontent-c1=""
            class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar"></span></span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar-wrapper" ng5sliderselbarelem=""
        style="visibility: hidden; width: 80px; left: 0px;"><span _ngcontent-c1=""
            class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bar ng5-slider-selection"
            ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></span></span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-pointer ng5-slider-pointer-min" ng5sliderminhelem=""
        ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuetext="Male(50%), Female(50%)"
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="slider" tabindex="0" style="left: 64px;"></span><span
        _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-pointer ng5-slider-pointer-max" ng5slidermaxhelem=""
        ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="display: none;"></span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bubble ng5-slider-limit ng5-slider-floor" ng5sliderflrlabelem=""
        style="visibility: hidden; left: 0px;">Male(0%), Female(100%)</span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bubble ng5-slider-limit ng5-slider-ceil" ng5sliderceillabelem=""
        style="visibility: hidden; left: -19px;">Male(100%), Female(0%)</span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bubble ng5-slider-model-value" ng5sliderminlabelem=""
        style="visibility: visible; left: -19px;">Male(50%), Female(50%)</span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bubble ng5-slider-model-high" ng5slidermaxlabelem=""
        style="visibility: hidden;"></span><span _ngcontent-c1=""
        class="ng5-slider-span ng5-slider-bubble ng5-slider-combined" ng5slidercmblabelem=""
        style="visibility: hidden;"></span><span _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng5-slider-ticks" ng5slidertickselem=""
        hidden="">
```

Any ideas if this is the control, angular or the styling part?

Comment: You could just put those styles you defined in `styles.scss` (the global styles file) and it will work. I consider this to be a better solution then to change _ViewEncapsulation_ since changing ViewEncapsulation to _None_ can affect all other styles in your entire app (which may produce undesired behavior)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one inside css file

```
::ng-deep {
    .custom-slider .ng5-slider .ng5-slider-selection {
        background: #DF495B;
      }
}
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 4):

add the **styles** to your styles.css of src folder

**or** add:

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

to your component to apply styles in scss of your component.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng5-slider-simple-slider-example-abqsrz).

Comment: My question was so blury didnt expect to get an answer and you just nail it. Thanks!   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None did it.

Comment: you're welcome. some libraries are not rendered in our main using component DOM so our page style doesn't have effect on them and should set their styles in global style file.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried so many different ways and finally find that the first you need to follow a path to enter like here am using parent is ng5-slider and then see in console its child elements and select the last one class from it and if you add it in global styles.css then you don't need to add ::ng-deep you can omit the ::ng-deep bracket.

```
::ng-deep {
    .ng5-slider {
        .ng5-slider-selection {
            background: $brand-blue !important;
        }
        .ng5-slider-floor,
        .ng5-slider-model-value,
        .ng5-slider-model-value,
        .ng5-slider-model-high,
        .ng5-slider-ceil,
        .ng5-slider-combined {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26189616)